# Firefox deleting specific cookie at end of session

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

I am creating a cookie using the following code:

```
var cnm="exampleCookie";
var exdays=365*4;
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";
expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=cnm + "=" + c_value;
```

However, instead of saving the cookie until the date it expires, Firefox (v 35.0.1) deletes the cookie when the session ends.  This does not happen in Chrome, and Firefox does not delete other cookies on the same site.  I've also used this same JS code on a github-hosted page and it retains the cookie after the browser closes.  Examining the cookie after it is set (using [Cookies Manager+ addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/)) shows that it is set with an expiration date.

How can I make it so Firefox stops deleting this cookie?

Answer (score 0):

For latest browsers to honor cookie expiration date you need to set `Max-Age` directive. `Expires` is for old browsers like IE6, 7 & 8 and FF 3 and chrome early versions. Starting from HTTP 1.1, `Max-Age` is valid  in any standards compliant browser and all the latest versions are fully compliant. When in doubt or if you need to support old browsers as well set both of them, but careful with the values. `Expires` accepts a date string where as `Max-Age` takes seconds like `Max-Age=31536000` which means it will expire after 1 year starting from the moment the browser received the cookie

Comment: Changed it to `var c_value=escape("1")+"; max-age=999999999; expires="+exdate.toUTCString();` but the cookie is still deleted when the browser closes.

Comment: Can u pls add the console.log of final cookie string before adding it to your document ?

Comment: `testCookie=1; max-age=999999999; expires=Wed, 15 Nov 2017 19:32:17 GMT`